# Is mutual Transport Layer Security (mTLS) supported by React Native? If yes, can you please share a working example

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement mTLS in react-native but could not find any working example on internet.

Comment: Looking at this [old issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10885) it seems you couldn't do it back then and I've found nothing to suggest it can be done now. But there is a work around listed there.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to achieve it for android by changing the java code and creating a react native module.

Keep your certs in android/app/src/main/assets

Here is the code:

```
package com.appName;//replace it with your app package name
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class HTTPRequestModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    ReactApplicationContext reactApplicationContext;
    OkHttpClient client;
    HTTPRequestModule(ReactApplicationContext reactApplicationContext) {
        super(reactApplicationContext);
        this.reactApplicationContext = reactApplicationContext;
        this.client = setUpClient();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "HTTPRequest";
    }

    private OkHttpClient setUpClient(){
        try {
            final String SECRET = "secret"; // You may also store this String somewhere more secure.
            CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            AssetManager am = reactApplicationContext.getAssets();

            // Get private key
//            InputStream privateKeyInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key);
            InputStream privateKeyInputStream = am.open("cert.key");
            byte[] privateKeyByteArray = new byte[privateKeyInputStream.available()];
            privateKeyInputStream.read(privateKeyByteArray);

            String privateKeyContent = new String(privateKeyByteArray, Charset.defaultCharset())
                    .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                    .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                    .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");


            byte[] rawPrivateKeyByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(rawPrivateKeyByteArray);

            // Get certificate
            InputStream certificateInputStream = am.open("cert.pem");
            Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificateInputStream);

            // Set up KeyStore
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(null, SECRET.toCharArray());
            keyStore.setKeyEntry("client", keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec), SECRET.toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{certificate});
            certificateInputStream.close();

            // Set up Trust Managers
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

            // Set up Key Managers
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, SECRET.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

            // Obtain SSL Socket Factory
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            // Finally, return the client, which will then be used to make HTTP calls.
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0])
                    .build();

            return client;

        } catch (CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException |
                 UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = true)
    public String getRequest(String token, String url) {
       try {
           Request request = new Request.Builder()
                   .url(url)
                   .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).build();
           Call call = this.client.newCall(request);
           Response response =  call.execute();


           Log.d("HTTPRequest", String.valueOf(response.code()));

           return  response.body().string();
//           return "Sample request is being called";
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       }

    }
    
}
```

Use this module to create the react Native module

```
package com.appName;//replace it with your app package name
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class HTTPRequestPackage implements ReactPackage {

    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new HTTPRequestModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactApplicationContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Here is how you reference this module in your typescript file

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
const { HTTPRequest } = NativeModules;

export const getUserFiles = (token: string) => {
  // return axios.get<string[]>(FILES_URL)
  const response = HTTPRequest.getRequest(token, FILES_URL);
  return JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with Axios?

Comment: I was unable to find a method to accomplish it using Axios.